# Problems with changing identification field in IP header using RAW socket

Tags: header, ip, field, identification

I have created a RAW socket and set the socket option as "IP_HDRINCL". I am setting the identification field in the outgoing UDP packet and

sending the  same out. I see that this field is changed to a random number when the packet is sent out. I can see the same in the sniffer capture.

The same code when built and tested in a different Windows XP machine, works fine ie. I can see that the identification field in the IP header of the outgoing packet carries the same value that I have set.

Not sure whats going wrong. Please let me if you have any insights.

Thanks,

Renu

Answer (score 0):

Raw sockets with `IP_HDRINCL` automatically set the values of certain field of ip packets that are going to get sent out.

In your case, the packet id will get overwritten in case is zero. (is it your case?)

This are the cases: (taken from [Raw Socket man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/raw.7.html))

```
          +---------------------------------------------------+
          |IP Header fields modified on sending by IP_HDRINCL |
          +----------------------+----------------------------+
          |IP Checksum           |Always filled in.           |
          +----------------------+----------------------------+
          |Source Address        |Filled in when zero.        |
          +----------------------+----------------------------+
          |Packet Id             |Filled in when zero.        |
          +----------------------+----------------------------+
          |Total Length          |Always filled in.           |
          +----------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am setting the same to non zero value. The code works fine in Windows 7 and some Windows XP machines strangely ie I see the identification field has the value I have set in the outgoing packet. Also in the same XP machines sometimes it works fine sometimes the identification field is overwritten.

Comment: Did you try to keep the size of the packets under the machine MTU size? Since the id field is used for IP fragmentation, maybe the OS mangle it. Try to send small (less than 1500bytes) packets and watch what happens.

Comment: I am sending packet of size 63 bytes which includes IP header, UDP header and the payload. Also the fragmentation offset in IP header is set to 0x4000 which corresponds to dont fragment flag. Strangely the ID field was not changing in one XP machine initially and suddenly stopped working ie was being over written by random number.